# Problema al momento de crear backup de MySQL desde Java

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema el cual ya no puedo darle mas vueltas porque no se que ocurre, sucede lo siguiente:

Tengo una base de datos la  cual ya esta en uso hasta ahora tiene 147 KB entre la estructura y los datos. Bueno, si uso la consola para hacer el Backup de esta manera:

```
<RUTA_DE_MYSQL>\mysqldump --opt --password=<CONTRASEÑA> --user=root <BASE_DE_DATOS> > <RUTA_DE_DESTINO>\Backup.sql
```

y funciona perfecto, osea aparece un .sql con todos los datos de 145 KB, ahora bien, en Java hago esto:

> ```
>     private static void backup() {
>     //Carpeta que contendra el Backup:
>     File carpeta = new File(<RUTA_CONTENEDORA_BACKUP>);
>     carpeta.mkdirs();
>     //*
>     //Creacion del .sql
>     Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
>     File backup = new File(<RUTA_CONTENEDORA_BACKUP> + "\\Backup.sql");
>     try {
>         InputStreamReader isr;
>         BufferedReader br;
>         FileWriter fileWriterGeneral = new FileWriter(backup);
>         Process child = runtime.exec("<RUTA_DE_MYSQL>\\mysqldump  --opt --user=root --password=<CONTRASEÑA>--databases <CONTRASEÑA> -R");
>         isr = new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream());
>         br = new BufferedReader(isr);
>         //*
>         //Pasar todo al .sql
>         String line;
>         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
>             fileWriterGeneral.write(line + " \n");
>         }
>         isr.close();
>         br.close();
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
> ```

Bueno al momento de compilar y ejecutar el programa sucede que el resultado es un .sql de 144 KB, luego de notar que cuando hice el Restore en la base de datos a partir de ese .sql me lanso 1 error. Al momento de verificar ese .sql vi que al final, se corta el archivo, me explico a que me refiero con "corta":

cuando hago un backup el .sql que se genera tiene como ultima linea esto:

```
-- Dump completed on <FECHA_DEL_BACKUP> <HORA_DEL_BACKUP>
```

pero en el .sql que yo genero a partir de mi codigo Java eso no esta sino que se interrumpe desde cierto punto asi sin mas.

Lo que trate fue lo siguiente:

> Crei que el problema era aqui "(line = br.readLine())", que al momento de que a la variable "line" se le pase lo que tiene "br.readLine()" no era capas de almacenar toda la linea y que por eso se cortaba, entonces probe esto:
>
> ```
>     //Pasar todo al .sql
>     String line;
>     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
>         System.out.println(line);  
>         fileWriterGeneral.write(line + " \n");
>     }
> ```

Trate de ver el contenido de "line" con el System.out.println() para ver si efectivamente se cortaba el contenido en algun punto, pero en la consola todo esta perfecto en la consola veo TODO el backup linea por linea y efectivamente llega al final.

Es un gran problema porque si si "corta" en medio de el dump de una tabla. ningun registro se pasa a la base de datos como es el caso de una tabla en la que se para ahora por el registro 245 y por lo tanto ningun registro se pasa a la tabla y queda vacia PDT.: antes que nada verifique ese registro y no tiene nada que ver todo esta bien, es mas ese nisiquiera es el problema porque mientras trataba de areglarlo el orden de las tablas cambio en el .sql y se paraba en otro lado.

Espero puedan ayudarme porque la verdad no entiendo que ocurre... gracias de antemano..

Comment: Haces `flush` del `fileWriter`?

Comment: me siento avergonzado...  utilize el flush y.... si un .sql de 147 KB... muchísimas gracias  SJuan76... rayos que vergüenza DX